# Converting pyspark to scala: Reading multiple directories

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a list of files in parquet format that I load and merge into one single dataframe in PySpark.

```
paths = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']
df_list = map(lambda x:(spark.read.parquet(x)), paths)
df = reduce(lambda df1, df2: df1.unionAll(df2), df_list)
```

I would like to do the same operation using Scala. However when I using map operation on a **Scala list of paths**

```
val df_list = map(x = > (spark.read.parquet(x)), paths)
```

I am getting the following error:

> :139: error: overloaded method value parquet with
>   alternatives:   (paths: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame 
>   (path: String)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame  cannot be applied to
>   (List[String])
>          val df_list = map(x = > (spark.read.parquet(x)), paths)

Any suggestion to resolve the issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
val df_list = paths.map(x => spark.read.parquet(x))
val df = df_list.reduce(_.union(_))
```

Issue is that in Scala `map` and `reduce` are collection methods.

Answer (score 2):

The preferred approach here would be to use skip `union` and load data directly with varargs:

```
spark.read.parquet(paths: _*)
```